# Dealing with json responses that may change (not all keys included every time, new keys could be added)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, json-deserialization

I need some pointers here.

I'm talking to an API that returns data based on specific parameters. I have been taking that response and flattening/editing it to fit my model and then saving into the database. Everything was working great until today that I started testing the live endpoint (no dummy data) and as it turns out, the format of the response changes.

For example, if a data set does not have a record, rather than including the value as nil, some responses are not including that key at all. This is breaking my logic to flatten and edit since now I'd need to check that every single field exists before I do anything.

Here are 2 snippets of what it can look like

Sample 1 - (No shared)

```
{
    "request_info": {
        "city_id": 76211,
        "currency": "usd",
        "req_type": "geom"
    },
    "data": {
        "rental_counts": {
            "counts": {
                "private": {
                    "1": 17,
                    "2": 3,
                    "all": 20
                },
                "entire": {
                    "0": 2,
                    "1": 8,
                    "2": 11,
                    "3": 16,
                    "4": 14,
                    "5": 6,
                    "all": 57
                }
            },
        }
    }
}
```

Sample 2 (includes Shared)

```
{
    "request_info": {
        "city_id": 76211,
        "currency": "usd",
        "req_type": "geom"
    },
    "data": {
        "rental_counts": {
            "counts": {
                "private": {
                    "1": 17,
                    "2": 3,
                    "all": 20
                },
                "entire": {
                    "0": 2,
                    "1": 8,
                    "2": 11,
                    "3": 16,
                    "4": 14,
                    "5": 6,
                    "all": 57
                },
                "shared": {
                    "0": 2,
                    "1": 8,
                    "all": 10
                }
            },
        }
    }
}
```

The changes I believe can happen at any level and for any key (parent or child). I'm sure I'm not the first one to run into something like this. What is the best way to manage it? Is there some method or gem that would help with parsing json and getting it into a standardized model whether the data keys are there or not?

I had been looking at Roar but still don't quite understand how it works very well. Is this something Roar could handle or would the json object need to be pre-defined and not dynamic?

Comment: Could you share some code related to how the flattening is being performed or how the parameters are being permitted while saving?

Comment: I'm using the  transform_key method and hash.delete to rename some of the fields and remove the nesting. For saving, I'm using active record import and passing an array of hashes that contains the key-value records for each field. With this strategy, if the response ever includes an additional field the import would fail or if a transformed key is missing, without an if statement to verify all those keys needing transformation exist, the flattening will fail as well.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simpler solution than roar or deserializers. Ruby's slice method allows you to only select pre defined keys and ignore all others. I'm calling this method after flattening my hash but before using active record to import.